# jQuery interval questin about extra click function

Tags: jquery, click, setinterval

I have this javascript code:

```
var listitem = $(".landkaart > ul > li"),
                    len = listitem.length,
                    index = 0;

                $(".landkaart > ul > li:first").addClass('open');

                setInterval( function() {
                    $(".landkaart > ul > li").removeClass('open');

                    if( ( index + 1 ) >= len )
                    {
                        index = 0;
                        $(".landkaart > ul > li:first").addClass('open');
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        listitem.eq( index ).next().addClass('open');
                    }
                    index++;
                }, 5000);
```

And i have the html,

```
<div class="landkaart">
                <ul>
                    <li><a class="doetinchem" title="Vestiging Doetinchem" href="vestigingen.html">Doetinchem</a>
                        <div class="doetinchem">
                            <div class="pijl"></div>
                            <ul>
                                <li><h2>Doetinchem</h2></li>
                                <li>Gildenbroederslaan 4</li>
                                <li>Postbus 196</li>
                                <li>7000 AD Doetinchem</li>
                                <li>Telefoon (0314) 37 70 00</li>
                                <li>Telefax (0314) 37 70 05</li>
                                <li><a class="email" href="mailto:doetinchem@kabaccountants" title="Stuur een mail naar: doetinchem@kabaccountants">doetinchem@kabaccountants</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

The html have a lot of more li items than here show. But now my question.
            Now the .landkaart ul li items rotate. Over 5 sec you see a new li item that come show.
            But now must the javascript make sow. That when i hover ".landkaart a" The landkaart > li must be show and
            the interval must be stop. When i go with the mouseout. Then the interval must be start again.

Comment: What's the css for this?

Answer (score 0):

I would do that by:

1. Move the function outside of the
   setInterval
2. Put boolean logic to stop changing
   if the cursor is over
3. Add your mouseover/out events to the li elements

   ```
          var keepRotating = true;
          function rotate() {
               if(!keepRotating) return;
               $(".landkaart > ul > li").removeClass('open');


           if( ( index + 1 ) &gt;= len )
           {
               index = 0;
               $(".landkaart &gt; ul &gt; li:first").addClass('open');
           }
           else
           {
               listitem.eq( index ).next().addClass('open');
           }
           index++;
       }


       $(".landkaart &gt; ul &gt; li").mouseover(function(){
         keepRotating = false;
         $(".landkaart &gt; ul &gt; li").removeClass('open');
         $(this).addClass('open');
         index = $(".landkaart &gt; ul).index(this);
       });


       $(".landkaart &gt; ul &gt; li").mouseout(function(){
         keepRotating = true;
       });


       setInterval( rotate(), 5000);
   ```

Comment: This is not working. I try to paste this code in my editor. But it give errors....

Comment: nothing. It is not working. I copy and paste the code in my dreamwaver. But it is not working...

Comment: Make sure you debug it properly. The SO editor escaped the less/greater than signs that you'll have to change back.